# Run a app from terminal and send a password

Tags: shiny

I want to launch a shiny application from a terminal to avoid blocking the rstudio console.

My application uses the ssh package to connect to a remote machine.

When I launch the application from rstudio a small window opens to ask me for my password but when I launch the application from the terminal i get an error message.

```
$ "Rscript.exe" -e "shiny::runApp('app')"
Loading required package: shiny
Warning: package 'shiny' was built under R version 3.5.3
Warning: package 'ssh' was built under R version 3.5.3
Linking to libssh v0.8.6
Password callback did not return a string value
Erreur : Authentication with ssh server failed
Stopped
```

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ssh)

ssh.session <- ssh::ssh_connect(host = host)
cat("*** Logging in of the session ***")

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage()

server <- function(input, output) {

  onStop(function() {
    ssh_disconnect(ssh.session)
    cat("*** Logging out of the session ***")
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about your security necessity in your use case...

What you could'd do (if its ok for you to specify a password while calling Rscript), is giving the password as an extra parameter when calling `RScript` and then forwarding it to `ssh_connect()`. You could also do the same with host variable. Im calling this R file via:

```
Rscript --vanilla home/user/R/app.R "password"
```

I'm not running `shiny::runApp`, because the line `shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)` will automatically start up the shiny application, allowing us to connect to ssh beforehand.

In the app.R file we forward the arguments to ssh_connect.

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ssh)
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
host="host"
ssh.session <- ssh::ssh_connect(host = host,passwd = )
cat("*** Logging in of the session ***")

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage()

server <- function(input, output) {

  onStop(function() {
    ssh_disconnect(ssh.session)
    cat("*** Logging out of the session ***")
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```